# Can the On-Premises Data Gateway and Data Management Gateway coexist on the same cluster?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

We currently have a highly available cluster of the Data Management Gateway for an Azure Data Factory solution. Now we need to deploy a highly available On-Premises Data Gateway for a Logic Apps Solution.

The question is, can both agents co-exist on the same cluster? Are there any limitations on this setup?

Comment: I'm afraid they probably can't coexist but you can have a try if you can install both of them.

Comment: Give it a try is not good enough for production :) I'd need to know if that set up is supported by Microsoft.